# Share parent path between Custom Post Types and Pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, pages, url-rewriting, child-pages

Here's my situation:

I have a custom post type I created called "professions" with three professions ("military", "firefighters", "law-enforcement").

I created a page `single-professions.php` to use as the post page.

I set the slug to "heroes" in my `register_post_type` function:

`'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'heroes', 'with_front' => false )`

Here are the full options I set in `register_post_type`:

`$args = array(
        'label'               => 'professionals',
        'description'         => 'Professions of clients served',
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'revisions', 'custom-fields' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'heroes', 'with_front' => false ),
        'menu_position'       => 25,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page'
    );`

My URL structure for each type looks like the following:

```
/heroes/military/
/heroes/firefighters/
/heroes/law-enforcement/
```

I also created a page type called "heroes":

`/heroes/`

In addition, I created a page called "signup" and set it's parent to "heroes":

`/heroes/signup/`

However, the child page 404's (the parent page url does not, I think due to `has_archive => false`).

Is it possible to have child pages and custom posts share the same parent path?